# Pygame How To Make A Sprite A Have A Rect Attribute

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have two sprite one is my character and another one is my enemy.How would I make both them have a rect attribute so I can use rect collision in pygame.Anything would help me.
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#WINDOW
WIDTH = 352
HEIGHT = 122
pygame.display.set_caption('My First Python Game')
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))



#LOADING IMAGES
pg = "player.gif"
ey = "rat.gif"
bg = "y.gif"

enemy = pygame.image.load(ey)
player = pygame.image.load(pg)
spriteWidth, spriteHeight = player.get_rect().size
background = pygame.image.load(bg)

#MUSIC
pygame.mixer.music.load("music.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0.0)

#X & Y AXIS
x = 0
y = 0

 #Main Game Loop
   while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
     pygame.quit()
    sys.exit
    x = min(max(x, 0), WIDTH - spriteWidth)
    y = min(max(y, 0), HEIGHT - spriteHeight)
    screen.blit(background,[0,0])
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
     if event.key == pygame.K_s:
      x  += 45
    screen.blit(player, (y,x))
    pygame.display.update()
    if x <= WIDTH:
      x = 0
    if y <= HEIGHT:
      y = 0
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 3):

Create a player class, and do it that way, passing the image in at construction:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, image, x, y, screen):
        self.image = image
        self.width = image.get_width()
        self.height = image.get_height()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.screen = screen

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
```